# Java JPA: How to use multiple DB-users?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I think about using JPA for a webapp. But every user should have its own DB-user/schema.
Data of every single user should be private and hidden from all others.

As far I see I need to give JPA a single DB connection (including a user).

Is it possible to use different DB-users in one application?

Comment: One database connection per user cannot scale.  You can partition the data in the database with a single connection.

Comment: You are talking about different tables or views?

Comment: Neither - connections.